# Solution required for the query related to Visual Source Safe 6.0d

Tags: visual-sourcesafe, vssget

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2003 Enterprise Developer Tool(**Visual Source Safe 6.0d**). As per my knowledge, In VSS there is a provision for admin to provide the access(r/w access or checkin / checkout access) to the given specific user for a perticular folder(that is having no. of different types of files) in a project. But I want to know, Is there any provision at Admin level to provide the access for a specific file (that is in a folder) to any given user.

Answer (score 0):

There is no file-based security setting support in VSS, as far as I know